# How to insert into gridview by using button in devexpress?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms, devexpress

I made a Grid view and already made the Data source to select and insert new row into the database. What I want to ask is how can I access insert command inside the grid view and execute it using button click?

Comment: Please add at least some indication of what you've already tried, including a description of what the exact problem is you're running in to.

Answer (score 0):

In the Click event handler, call the View’s

> GridView.AddNewRow

method.

```
private void bAddRow_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    gridView1.AddNewRow();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but when i click the button, the gridview display insert form. how to disable this form

Comment: how to hide gridview form when insert new row?

Comment: @patrixx In what way to you wish to insert the data of new row if not within a form?